# Is there a cojoin, the dual construction of the join of topological spaces?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, category-theory, pullback

The [join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/join_(topology)) $X\star Y$ of topological spaces $X$ and $Y$ [can alternatively be written](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/join+of+topological+spaces) as a homotopy pushout of the canonical diagram $X\leftarrow X\times Y\rightarrow Y$:
\begin{equation}
X\star Y
=X\stackrel{h}{+}_{X\times Y}Y.
\end{equation}
What about the dual construction, the homotopy pullback of the canonical diagram $X\rightarrow X+Y\leftarrow Y$, written as $X\stackrel{h}{\times}_{X+Y}Y$? I haven't found anything about it yet. I suspect it to be empty (and therefore uninteresing) because of disjoint images in the mentioned diagram, but is that true and if yes, how can it be argued elegantly? I think, there should be a short argument involving cofibrations.

Comment: It is indeed empty. More interesting in the pointed case, I guess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The construction comes up in the pointed category. Thus for based spaces $X,Y$ let $X\mathop{\hat\ast} Y$ be the homotopy pullback of the triad
$$X\xrightarrow{in_X}X\vee Y\xleftarrow{in_Y}Y.$$
I guess we can call this the *cojoin* of $X,Y$.

This space is generally non-trivial and is related to the so-called *flat product* $X\mathop{\flat} Y$, which is defined be the homotopy fibre of the inclusion
$$X\vee Y\hookrightarrow X\times Y.$$
In fact, for path-connected, well-pointed spaces $X,Y$ there is a homotopy equivalence
$$X\mathop{\hat\ast} Y\simeq \Omega(X\mathop{\flat} Y)\simeq \Omega\Sigma(\Omega X\wedge\Omega Y).$$

The cojoin construction comes up when $X=Y$ and $X$ is a co-H-space with comultiplication $c:X\rightarrow X\vee X$. In this case $c$ induces a morphism of triads from
$$\ast \rightarrow X\leftarrow \ast$$
to
$$X\xrightarrow{in_1}X\vee X\xleftarrow{in_2}X,$$
and taking homotopy pullbacks yields the *coHopf construction* $H'(c)$ as a map
$$H'(c):\Omega X\rightarrow X\mathop{\hat\ast} Y.$$
The *coprojective plane* of $(X,c)$ is defined to be the homotopy fibre of $H'(c)$. In case $c$ is suitably coassociative, this construction can be repeated so as to yield higher coprojective planes.

This is nicely dual to the theory of projective planes for H-spaces and higher projective planes for $A_n$-spaces. However, unlike the dual theory, things quickly breaks down, and I don't know of any real use for the coprojective planes.

Comment: You might try `\mathop{…}` to get better spacing on your binary operators.

Comment: Thank you for giving more insight to the background! This looks like what I looked for, when searching for a cojoin. But I constantly assumed, that it should be done in total analogy to the join, which just didn't work out. I'm happy to see, that there is indeed such a construction!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the pullback is empty, in fact any $Z \to X + Y$ that factors as both $Z \to X \to X+ Y$ and $Z \to Y \to X +Y$ must have $Z$ empty: for any $z \in Z$, $z \to X \to X + Y$ is homotopic to $z \to Y \to X + Y$. But $[0,1]$ is connected so there is no such $z$.

Comment: That is a very simple argument, I totally oversaw. Thank you!

Comment: @SamuelAdrianAntz Happy to help and to learn about the interesting answer by Tyrone. And I think you mean overlooked :)

Comment: Oh, yes! Overlooked. :-) (The german translation means "oversaw".)